# how to limit number of entries in a db of redis

Tags: redis

I am running a redis instance and want to limit the number of keys in an DB of the instance.
I checke the documentation and I saw that we can limit the memory of a complete instance .Any way to do that on DB level?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

No, Redis does not have a function that can limit the amount of keys in the database.

The closest thing I can think of is checking the key number in your script, and the preventing the query of there is too many keys in the databse